# How to get a list of all products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product

How can I get a list of all available products in Magento 2?

Comment: My answer hasn't helped you?

Comment: Mark now @SiarheyUchukhlebau answer as correct....

Answer (score 35):

You should use `Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository` or `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection` according your needs.  You can use both methods to get product instances with all data.

#### Example 1 (Repository):

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->searchCriteria = $criteria;
    $this->filterGroup = $filterGroup;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;

    $this->getProductData();
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Cms\Model\Block|null
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
protected function getProductData()
{

    $this->filterGroup->setFilters([
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('status')
            ->setConditionType('in')
            ->setValue($this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds())
            ->create(),
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('visibility')
            ->setConditionType('in')
            ->setValue($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
            ->create(),
    ]);

    $this->searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$this->filterGroup]);
    $products = $this->productRepository->getList($this->searchCriteria);
    $productItems = $products->getItems();

    return $productItems;
}
```

**Result:**

[image: repository]

#### Example 2 (Collection):

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject[]
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function getProducts()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', ['in' => $this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds()]);

    return $collection->getItems();
}
```

**Result:**

[image: collection]

Comment: hi @siarhey, I am getting an empty result with your code. Do you have any tips about it? Could it be because of I am trying to retrieve the list from a cron task?

Comment: @LorenzoS Hi, which example you are using 1 or 2? Does any product exist when you remove all filters/conditions?

Comment: How do get this "Variables" tab with objects tree in your screenshot ?

Comment: @maxagaz Using [xDebug in PHPStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/configuring-xdebug.html)

Comment: great answer, @SiarheyUchukhlebau but what do you mean by  *If you need just product data use the first class. If you need to get the product instances - use second class.*

Comment: @YehiaA.Salam Sorry, it is a misunderstanding of the repository mechanism from my side. You can use both methods to get product instances with all data.

Answer (score 11):

The most upvoted answer is working but I would like to mention that here by injecting a product repository implementation directly will cause the breach of service contract principle & that is something Magento wants developers to correct. 
You should inject `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository` instead of it's implementation which is `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository`.
That way you you will have a space for future upgrade ability. Bottom line is use Service contracts as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Using a REST API call:

```
https://{host}/rest/V1/products/?searchCriteria=
```

Retrieves all products. "searchCriteria" is a required param, but can be left blank, as above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through api request. Take a look at the default m2 [api](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html)

think your better shoot is catalogProductRepositoryV1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Moazzam\LatestProduct\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json;
use Magento\Staging\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

/**
 * Excute the list of products
 *
 * Class Index
 */
class Index implements HttpPostActionInterface, HttpGetActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    protected SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteria;

    /**
     * @var FilterBuilder
     */
    protected FilterBuilder $filterBuilder;

    /**
     * @var JsonFactory
     */
    protected JsonFactory $jsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        JsonFactory $jsonFactory
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->searchCriteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterBuilder=$filterBuilder;
        $this->jsonFactory=$jsonFactory;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the list of  products through search critarea
     *
     * @return Json
     */
    public function execute(): Json
    {
        $filters = $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('name')
            ->setConditionType('like')
            ->setValue('%hoodie%')
            ->create();
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteria->addFilter($filters)
            ->addSortOrder('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->setPageSize(20)
            ->setCurrentPage(1)
            ->create();
        $products = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $getData[] = [
                'sku' => $product->getSku(),
                'name' => $product->getName()
            ];
        }
        return $this->jsonFactory->create()->setData($getData);
    }
}
```