# Magento 2 - how to get models, config(s), and order info similar to Magento 1 style (Mage::getBaseUrl, Mage::getModel, etc...))

Tags: magento2, model, singleton

I am a complete Magento 2 noob. I know a lot of things changed, one of which is how to get the Singleton `Mage::` instance and its methods. I know it is moved to vendor/ directory from Mage/Code/Core, but I still don't know how to call `Mage::` and invoke the methods for getting the model and other things, like order total amount, and order items. I need this in order to implement a module, but also independently of the module, in a pure PHP page. How can I access Magento methods in Magento 2? I tried:

```
namespace Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product;
$objectManager = Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

but it didn't work, I got the error message:

```
Class 'Vendor\Module_Name\Block\Product\Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/retrieveTotalOrders.php on line 8
```

Comment: This is very broad question. Please narrow down what exactly u want to achieve like Customer, Product, etc..

Comment: Particularly, I need information about product (product name, attributes) and order total amount, order items.

Comment: I edited the question. My problem is that I can't get reference to the object manager.

Comment: Use di for get factories You need. Eg for products: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130185/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-products-in-magento-2

Comment: I need to get object manager.

Comment: Refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140612/magento-2-save-all-product-data-outside-magento-with-images

Answer (score 1):

This is not **valid class**

```
$objectManager = Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Use instead

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
```

Comment: `;;` ? Meaning. It's not valid right?

Comment: @AnkitShah `;;` typo also that not valid i check that now. thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code for call model anywhere

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$model = $objectManager->create('\Namespace\Modulename\Model\Modulename');
```