# Magento 2 programatically get special price product collection

Tags: magento2, product, products, special-price

How can i programatically get special price product collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get products with a special price greater then 0 using product repository with search criteria:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->searchCriteria = $criteria;
    $this->filterGroup = $filterGroup;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
}

/**
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getProductData()
{

    $this->filterGroup->setFilters([
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('special_price')
            ->setConditionType('gt')
            ->setValue(0)
            ->create(),
    ]);

    $this->searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$this->filterGroup]);
    $products = $this->productRepository->getList($this->searchCriteria);
    $productItems = $products->getItems();

    return $productItems;
}
```

Result should be like this:

[image: result]

#### UPDATE:

If you want to filter selected items by visibility & status - just add corresponding filters:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface $criteria,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup $filterGroup,
    \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->searchCriteria = $criteria;
    $this->filterGroup = $filterGroup;
    $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Cms\Model\Block|null
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getProductData()
{

    $this->filterGroup->setFilters([
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('special_price')
            ->setConditionType('gt')
            ->setValue(0)
            ->create(),
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('status')
            ->setConditionType('in')
            ->setValue($this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds())
            ->create(),
        $this->filterBuilder
            ->setField('visibility')
            ->setConditionType('in')
            ->setValue($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds())
            ->create(),
    ]);

    $this->searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$this->filterGroup]);
    $products = $this->productRepository->getList($this->searchCriteria);
    $productItems = $products->getItems();

    return $productItems;
}
```

Comment: In the above code i am getting all the products with special price, Is there anyway to get the products that are currently active in special price..

Comment: @srg Yes, just modify your search criteria. You can find an example [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130185/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-products-in-magento-2)

Comment: I have tried but the result is same...i am getting all special products ..can you please  help me to apply search criteria..

Comment: @srg Please, see updated answer

Comment: i have tried in the same way that you have mentionde above.but the product with special price date is ended are also still listing in this. in this i think i want to check the current date, how can i check the end date and current date to display products.

Comment: @srg Please, ask another question and drop a link here. I'll try to help you create a combined filter for your purposes.

Comment: i have updated my question please find the below link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/188507/programatically-get-special-price-products-that-are-active-by-checking-the-end-d