# How to get *every* products (in stock, out of stock, enabled, disabled, etc..)

Tags: magento2, product-collection, stock

I've been trying to figure this out for too many hours now...

How can I fetch every products from the database?

I've tried a lot of different method of getting the products, but all of them either don't work at all or only return products in stock.

This is what I'm using at the moment and it returns every products in stock (5 products out of the ~50 products that I can see in the admin):

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->load();

foreach ($collection->getItems() as $productItem) {
    $product = $productItem->getData();
    echo $product['name'].'<br>';
}
```

If it matters, my goal is to update these products (name, description, stock, price...).

Comment: print_r(get_class_methods($product)); you will get list of methods . Accordingly you can think

Comment: You can update product name,description, stock etc by using csv also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of Pankaj Pareek.

I just added `$collection->setFlag('has_stock_status_filter', false);` and now I get every products.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `status` and `visibility` filter in collection to fetch all Products:

```
/**
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility
) {
    $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
    $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
}

/**
 * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject[]
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
 */
public function getProducts()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
    $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product/status', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->joinAttribute('visibility', 'catalog_product/visibility', 'entity_id', null, 'inner');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', ['in' => $this->productStatus->getVisibleStatusIds()])
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', ['in' => $this->productVisibility->getVisibleInSiteIds()]);

    return $collection->getItems();
}
```

You can check more on below links:

[How to get a list of all products in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130185/how-to-get-a-list-of-all-products-in-magento-2)

[How to get only out of stock products in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/157193/how-to-get-only-out-of-stock-products-in-magento-2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I just tried your solution, but it doesn't work, there are no change in the result i'm getting (and no error either). It seems like the products are filtered to only return in stock items even before we get to filter the collection.

Comment: Can you try to print sql using $collection->getSelect() to check what conditions are applying

Comment: Without your code added, it's `SELECT e.* FROM catalog_product_entity AS e`, with your code, see https://pastebin.com/TACnaje9

Comment: When I run the first query in mysql it returns 51 rows.

Comment: `$collection->load(true);` gave this output: https://pastebin.com/6CujUncN

Answer (score 0):

You can update product name,description, stock etc by using csv also, export product form admin

Login To Admin
Go To System => Export =>
Select Option As per Below and export product
Entity Type => Products

https://prnt.sc/i2yvjl
https://prnt.sc/i2yvhb

Form CSV you can remove extra fields and you can update name ,description etc by using SKU
In CSV Fileds like
**sku,name,description,price**

Comment: Sorry, I want to do this automatically.